# Add Click method to dyn button at VBA not work

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create dynamic buttons and then implement the click method, but any help on the internet does not work here. I hope someone can help me here.

It is not possible to create all buttons. Unfortunately, there is no possibility to write in other languages ​​because we can only use Excel and may.

This is about the `infoBtn1_Click`.

**My Script**

```
Option Explicit

Dim WithEvents infoBtn          As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim WithEvents infoBtn1          As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim WithEvents frameCard        As MSForms.frame
Dim WithEvents cardTitel        As MSForms.Label
Dim WithEvents ausLabel         As MSForms.Label
Dim WithEvents ausbilderLabel   As MSForms.Label
Dim WithEvents amLabel          As MSForms.Label
Dim WithEvents datumLabel       As MSForms.Label
Dim WithEvents infoLabel        As MSForms.Label

Dim add                         As Integer
Dim topPos                      As Integer
Dim ctl                         As Control
Dim n                           As Integer
Dim VorhabenArray()             As Variant
Dim Free(1 To 5)                As Long
Dim sh                          As Worksheet
Dim v                           As Range
Dim arr(0 To 40)                As Integer
Dim i                           As Integer
Dim ausbildungNr                As String
Dim speicher                    As String


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Bitte tragen Sie eine Ausbildung ein."
    Exit Sub
    End If
    ausbildungSuche.ausbildungCB.Value = ComboBox1.Value
    Unload Me
    Call ausbildungSuche.suchenBtn_Click
End Sub

Private Sub infoBtn1_Click()
   MsgBox "test"
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()


    On Error GoTo fehler

    ComboBox1.List = Sheets("Meta").Range("A1:A8").Value
    speicher = ausbildungSuche.ausbildungCB.Value

Select Case speicher
    Case "MilFit":
        ausbildungNr = "1"
    Case "Circuit training":
        ausbildungNr = "2"
    Case "Volleyball":
        ausbildungNr = "3"
    Case "Fußball":
        ausbildungNr = "4"
    Case "Sportliche Ertuechtigung":
        ausbildungNr = "5"
    Case "BFT":
        ausbildungNr = "6"
    Case "DSA":
        ausbildungNr = "7"
    Case "Schwimmen":
        ausbildungNr = "8"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Fehler"
End Select


    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ausbildungNr)

    i = 0
    topPos = 12

    For Each v In sh.Range("M2:M100")
        If Not v = "0" Then

            Set frameCard = Controls.add("Forms.Frame.1", "frame" & i)
            With frameCard
                .Left = 144
                .Top = topPos
                .Width = 258
                .Height = 72
                .Caption = ""
                .Zoom = 100
                .SpecialEffect = 3
                .BorderColor = &H80000012
            End With

            Set cardTitel = frameCard.Controls.add("Forms.Label.1", "cardTitel" & i, True)
             With cardTitel
                .Left = 8
                .Top = 6
                .Width = 126
                .Height = 18
                .ForeColor = &H8000000D
                .Caption = v.Cells(, -10)
                .FontBold = True
                .FontSize = 12
            End With

            Set infoBtn = frameCard.Controls.add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "infoBtn" & i, True)
            With infoBtn
                .Left = 144
                .Top = 36
                .Width = 102
                .Height = 24
                .ForeColor = &HFFFFFF
                .BackColor = &H8000000D
                .Caption = v & " Plätze frei"
            End With

            Debug.Print "infoBtn" & i

            Set ausLabel = frameCard.Controls.add("Forms.Label.1", "ausLabel", Visible)
            With ausLabel
                .Left = 12
                .Top = 30
                .Width = 42
                .Height = 12
                .Caption = "Ausbilder"
            End With

            Set ausbilderLabel = frameCard.Controls.add("Forms.Label.1", "ausbilderLabel", Visible)
            With ausbilderLabel
                .Left = 54
                .Top = 30
                .Width = 72
                .Height = 12
                .FontBold = True
                .Caption = v.Cells(, -9)
            End With

            Set amLabel = frameCard.Controls.add("Forms.Label.1", "amLabel", Visible)
            With amLabel
                .Left = 12
                .Top = 48
                .Width = 24
                .Height = 12
                .Caption = "Am"
            End With

            Set datumLabel = frameCard.Controls.add("Forms.Label.1", "datumLabel", Visible)
            With datumLabel
                .Left = 54
                .Top = 48
                .Width = 72
                .Height = 12
                .FontBold = True
                .Caption = v.Cells(, -8)
            End With

            Set infoLabel = frameCard.Controls.add("Forms.Label.1", "infoLabel", Visible)
            With infoLabel
                .Left = 222
                .Top = 6
                .Width = 24
                .Height = 12
                .FontBold = True
                .Caption = "Info"
            End With

            topPos = frameCard.Top + frameCard.Height + 10
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

   ausbildungsfilter.Caption = ausbildungSuche.ausbildungCB.Value
    Exit Sub

fehler:     MsgBox "Das hat leider nicht geklappt."
    Unload Me


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a class module beside the user form. Here is a sample of the mechanic how dynamic events works:

Place this code in the module of an empty user form:

```
Option Explicit

Dim comSampleBtn1 As clsClickEventsComBut
Dim comSampleBtn2 As clsClickEventsComBut


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim comButTemp As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim commandButtonIndex As Byte

  commandButtonIndex = 1

  'Place sample button 1 and generate click event
  Set comButTemp = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1", "CommandButton" & commandButtonIndex, True)
  commandButtonIndex = commandButtonIndex + 1
  With comButTemp
    'Place button
    .Left = 50
    .Top = 50
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 100
    .Caption = "Sample Button 1"
    .ControlTipText = "Click me"
  End With
  Set comSampleBtn1 = New clsClickEventsComBut
  Set comSampleBtn1.ComButSample = comButTemp
  Set comButTemp = Nothing

  'Place sample button 2 and generate click event
  Set comButTemp = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1", "CommandButton" & commandButtonIndex, True)
  commandButtonIndex = commandButtonIndex + 1
  With comButTemp
    'Place button
    .Left = 50
    .Top = 75
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 100
    .Caption = "Sample Button 2"
    .ControlTipText = "Click me too"
  End With
  Set comSampleBtn2 = New clsClickEventsComBut
  Set comSampleBtn2.ComButSample = comButTemp
  Set comButTemp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now you need a class module with the name **clsClickEventsComBut**
Copy the following code to this module:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents ComButSample As MSForms.CommandButton


Private Sub ComButSample_Click()
  MsgBox "You clicked the sample button: " & UserForm1.ActiveControl.Name & Chr(13) & "With the caption: " & UserForm1.ActiveControl.Caption
End Sub
```

If you now click one of the two buttons, the message box will be show. This works with all controls.

Edit: New text for the message box with reference to the clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign this to the OnClick property of the button (usually on the OnLoad event or something similar):

```
infoBtn1.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
```

This assumes you have your `Private Sub InfoBtn1_Click` procedure declared like you have on your example code.
And note that it is this exact `"[Event Procedure]"` string that should be assigned to the `OnClick`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that does not work. I tried it in a different UserForm because it works, but without OnClick. I know this feature only with Java and not with VBA in Excel 2016.

Comment: One way around this would be to create a class having a button then instantiating it as an array. Like in here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b5fa6df-deb9-4a86-b172-88f604de8f30/event-for-dynamically-add-control-in-excel-vba?forum=isvvba You could use the Caption to distinguish between them on the event handler. By the way, the info buttons seem to be created one over the other (same positions).