# do an event on dynamic userform checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

i created a excel userform ( named `UserForm2`  `UserForm2.Show vbModeless`) and add checkbox dynamically get the value from a webpage.

so i named each checkbox with a unique name.

i want, for each checkbox, that if i check or uncheck starts a command that compares name and value of the selected checkbox with a string.

At least i have to create  and assign a command to each unique checkbox.

```
UserForm2.Show vbModeless
UserForm2.Width = 500
Dim vuoto As String
Dim thecheck, LstBx, lstbx1, LABELBx, LABELBx1, Button As Object
Dim labelCounter, Larray As Long
Dim arrList, arrList1, ListaURL As Variant
Larray = 0

For L = 1 To list.length - 1

    'Debug.Print L & "     Name: " & list.Item(L).Name, "Value: " & list.Item(L).value
    If InStr(1, list.Item(L).Name, ".descrizione") > 0 And InStr(1, list.Item(L).Name, "elencoSchemiDocum") > 0 Then

        labelCounter = labelCounter + 1

        Set thecheck = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.checkbox.1", , True)
        ' NOME OGGETTO DA USARE PER RECUPERO FLAG
        thecheck.Caption = list.Item(L).value    'etichetta della CHECKBOX
        thecheck.Left = 10
        thecheck.Width = 250
        thecheck.Top = 25 * labelCounter
        thecheck.Height = 20
    End If
    If InStr(1, list.Item(L).Name, ".impostazione") > 0 And InStr(1, list.Item(L).Name, "elencoSchemiDocum") > 0 Then
        thecheck.Name = list.Item(L).Name
        'thecheck.OnAction = "cambiato"
        thecheck.value = list.Item(L).value
    End If
```

Comment: I'm sure you don't really know what you're doing. I'm sorry, but to illustrate wherefrom I take this insolence: In VBA, every variable declared needs a data type. Without it, it'll be of type *Variant*. With *Dim x, y, z as Object*, only *z* is of the data type *Object*. *x* and *y* are of the data type *Variant*. This is basic knowledge and you ask for events for dynamically created UserForm elements. You can look here how to create dynamic events: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801868/add-click-method-to-dyn-button-at-vba-not-work

Comment: I beg your pardon sir...but It only a piece of the Whole code. I Just create a userform...by the way not in the best way of course...

Comment: It's not like I'm a full professional. I was just wondering. Were you able to solve your problem with the linked example?

Comment: well i used this...to try...problem now is pass variables from an array ( in the example is Namelist) or how set checkbox and other control as are in a web page...i m using winhttp..